# Preselect Filters not working in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have desinged summary chart by choosing the handlebars chart. Below is my handlebars template code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Filer Summary </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Filer Information </h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Filer ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>City</th>
        </tr>
            <ul class="data-list">
            {{#each data}}
            <tr>
                <td> <a href="/superset/dashboard/13/?preselect_filters={%2298%22:{%22FilerID%22:[16494]}}">{{FilerID}}</a> </td>
                <td> {{Name}} </td>
                <td> {{Type}} </td>
                <td> {{City}} </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </table>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my handlebars template code for Filer details dashboard

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Filer Information </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Filer Details </h1>
        <table>
            <ul class="data-list">
            {{#each data}}
            <tr>
                  <th>Filer ID</th>
                    <th>{{FilerID}}</th>
              </tr>
            <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>{{Name}}</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>{{Type}}</th>
              </tr>
            <tr>
                    <th>City</th>
                <th>{{City}}</th>
              </tr>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </table>    
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click the FilerID hipherlink in the summary dashboard, it is going to details dashboard, but not filtering the records based on the FilerID passed in the preselect filters. What I am missing here to make it work.

Below is the URL to my summary dashboard:

http://localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/12/

Expectation is to get the Filer details dashboard with filtered record details.